# Urlencoding weird characters in another charset

Tags: c, encoding, character-encoding, libcurl, iso

I'm learning C, and I'm using libcURL to send a POST request to log into a website.
I'm stumbling upon a problem, my password contains the `ü` character.
Reading the POST request from my browser, I can see it gets encoded as `%FC`.
However, when using `curl_easy_escape()` to encode it, it encodes as `%C3%BC`.

I've gone to search, and found out it's a different encoding. I think ISO, because the page has this meta: `<meta content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" http-equiv="content-type">`
However, I can't figure out how to convert it somehow.

Now, how would I go about urlencoding `ü`as `%FC`?

Comment: @HansPassant Why would I need to change the locale? Doesn't that only affect the output of multilingual programs?

Comment: It might be worth posting a separate question on the `libcurl` tag asking about the right/idiomatic way to prepare strings for use in POST. Since this is something everyone needs, surely there's a standard answer. The worst that could happen is that you find the standard solution is `curl_easy_escape` and that you're just supposed to do the charset conversion yourself before passing the string to this function.

Comment: @R.. Usually, if there's [an example from the library itself](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/http-post.html), I think that should be the right/idiomatic way to handle it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use of non-UTF-8 encodings for POST is an utter mess and the behavior actually varied quite a bit between browsers, so it's considered very bad practice to do this. But since you're stuck with a site that does, you'll have to work around it.

I can't find a curl api for doing percent encoding with alternate charsets so you might have to do it yourself (first use `iconv` to convert from your system's native encoding, hopefully UTF-8, to ISO-8859-1 (Latin-1), then do the percent encoding manually).

One idea - are you sure you even should be doing your own escaping? My impression is that it's just meant for URLs, and the curl API for POSTing forms may already do escaping internally (not sure), in which case you probably just have to tell it the right content type.

Comment: In libcURL, you just put a string in CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS. It doesn't do anything with it. iconv seems like a viable way, I'll try that. My program will take a command line argument for the password, should I worry about the encoding of said argument?

Comment: @mid_kid: Generally the polite thing to do is to treat anything coming from the command line, user-provided text files, env vars, etc. as being encoded in the locale's encoding. This requires calling `setlocale(LC_CTYPE, "")` or similar to ensure that the locale is honored and using `nl_langinfo(CODESET)` to get the name of the locale encoding (which you can then pass to `iconv_open`).